# how to store selective data in an array from json in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, leaflet, geojson

```
$.getJSON("rodents.geojson", function(data) {

    var ratIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'rat.png',
        iconSize: [40, 30]

    });

    L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {
                icon: ratIcon
            });
        }
    }).addTo(map);

    var pointlist[];
    var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointlist, {
        color: 'red',
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 0.5,
        smoothFactor: 1

    });
    firstpolyline.addTo(map);
});
```

i want to fill co ordinates from geojson data,i am drawing line for selected points from geojson points

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but from what i get i guess you should JSON.parse the data your getJSON returns and then use the variables in the json to create your line.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I get that you don't want all of the data but do you want a specific amount of items, like the first three, or do you want items with just part of all the properties they have? Also, that code doesn't look valid - is there a missing equals sign after `var pointlist`?